# getting id number from url and adding this to mysql where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, url

i have a link echoed out as part of a mysql query like so, and when clicked it will echo the id of this result into the url and go to my page 'insurance.php'

```
echo "<tr><td style=\"width:100px;\"><p><a href=\"insurance.php?id=".$row['id']."\" rel=\"shadowbox;height=700;width=1100\"\">".$row['id'] . "</a></p></td>";
```

in my page insurance.php i am wanting to echo out some results using a mysql query but want to add into the where clause of my query select * where id = the id in the url

can this be done? i am trying to use $_GET['id'] but not sure if i am using it propperly, it is not acknowledging this in the where clause, it still just shows all results with whatever id, please can someone show me where i am going wrong.

```
$id = (int)mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplier_stats, supplier_registration WHERE supplier_stats.company_reg_number = supplier_registration.company_reg_number AND supplier_stats.insurance_date = DATE(NOW()) AND supplier_stats.id = '$id';");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query2 )) {
```

Comment: well what is going wrong? Have you checked if your query is valid?

Comment: To debug such issues, you can save the query in a variable and echo it, then try that query on your phpMyAdmin. This will help pinpointing the problem.

Comment: (int)$_GET['id']; is enough for against sql injection....

Answer (score 0):

Even

```
(int)$_GET['id']
```

is not basicly wrong, you can also use

```
$myId = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

to get only the digits out of the 'id'-query-field and then use this $myId in your query.
The rest looks quite okay to me.